# Sleep Timers sleeping for wrong amount of time

Tags: autohotkey

I have a super simple script that just automates some repetitive, everyday stuff I do at work. The one I'm working on simply opens excel, pastes, formats, and filters some data.

However, I'm running into this peculiar issue where my `Sleep` timers aren't waiting the appropriate amount of time. I set one timer to `Sleep 5000` experimentally and found that it is consistently only delaying for approximately 3 seconds, while a timer shortly after that, set to `Sleep 2000`, is delaying appropriately. When I set the first timer to `Sleep 1000`, there is no discernible pause.

The exact code in question is:

```
Send, {right}{right}
Send, !{down}
Send, e
Send, FilterValue
sleep, 1000
Send, {down}{down}{space}{down}{space}{enter}
```

In excel, this block is simply meant to open the dropdown menu of the current column's filter, activates the search box, enters FilterValue, pauses, deselects "(Select All Search Results)", selects "Add current selection to filter" and confirms with enter.

Edit: I have this code block repeated immediately afterwards and its Sleep timer appears to be functioning properly.

Comment: Is FilterValue a literal string or meant to represent a variable (that has your value in it)?  In the meantime, it would appear your Sleep code should work, but if you keep having problems, use a `MsgBox` with the timeout set to your number of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that your system is mis-configured.
Maybe something altered the granularity of the system timer and now it is causing issues
There is nothing wrong with your script, it will be an environmental issue
Either that or you are wrong about the timing.
To check, use a script like this:

```
F12::
t := A_TickCount
Sleep 1000
t := A_TickCount - t
msgbox % t
return
```